# Differentiate between bounty and accepted answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounties, accepted-answer

I noticed that the color for a recieved bounty and an accepted answer are the same.

[image][image]

In the screen shot there is no difference for bounties and accepted answers. Can we have a little difference between the two. For example use the bounty indicator in rep changes for bounties.

[image]

Comment: This is only under the reputation summary? In the actual reputation tab bounties have a red background: [Bounty and Accepted answer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Wj7tk.png)

Comment: So, bounties can be black, red, blue and green..? Turn it all blue!

Comment: @3ventic Did you notice `For example use the bounty indicator in **rep changes** for bounties`.

Comment: @Tijesunimi Nope, but it's a good idea.