# Make bounty award color blue in summary tab

Tags: feature-request, design, bounties, reputation-summary

Accepts are green, that's good.

> [image]

But why is the color of bounties green in summary, recent rep?

> [image]

Bounties are blue everywhere, so make them blue there!

> [image]

So can we change the color of bounties from green to blue? It would make a whole lot more sense and better to differentiate rep earned from accepts and bounties.

Comment: +70 is a mix of bounty and something else (+20) though. Are you proposing to make the square blue if *any* of the rep in it came from a bounty?

Comment: @Jason yes, as with accepts: if any of rep comes in with accept on this post, it has green background.

Comment: @JasonC Just look at the full reputation tab of the profile.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209471/differentiate-between-bounty-and-accepted-answers

Comment: @Inf tssss.  Anyway, thats what the bounties for. :D

Comment: @Inf Now closing is impossible as it will lead to recursion :)

Comment: I know nic, that's why I answered it ;)

Comment: Now this post can be used as a dupe target to close other blue bounty posts because it has upvoted answers!

Comment: Noice freehand circle, even if they aren't red.

Comment: I changed the [tag:summary] to [tag:reputation-summary], seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 15):

I agree. Blue would be more meaningful than green.

It will make the UI more consistent, because it appears blue in the full reputation tab of the profile and green in the recent rep summary at present. This has been reported by [others in the past as well.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209471/245167)

Please make it blue!

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't a bounty just be separate from the other rep changes? Blue for bounties and votes might confuse some people ("why does it say I got 70 rep for a bounty?").

Since people don't get bounties often, it makes sense to emphasize them too.

Comment: But... It will inconsistent. All events on one post are grouped. Anyway, better than current behavior :)

Comment: @nicael But my mommy says bounties are *special*.

Comment: Not special for me :D

Comment: @nicael Only cos of the Socks :P

Comment: You could put a blue rectangle with the amount earned from the bounty to the left of (below?) the existing one—kind of like the indicator on the answer awarded the bounty.