# Bountied reputation changes treated as accepted answers

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page, bounties, accepted-answer

I recently got a bounty here on SO:

[how to round/remove traling ".0" zeros in pandas column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42403907/how-to-round-remove-traling-0-zeros-in-pandas-column/59334568#59334568)

But when I look at the summary page of my activity, it's colored green and it's the same color as an accepted answer:

[image]

Is this meant to be like this or is it just a bug?

Comment: Is there a way to reproduce it now that you've had more reputation changes and it's been bumped off the summary page?

Comment: So that others can see, a mod (on any site) might be able to find a [recently awarded bounty](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375795/how-can-i-find-recently-awarded-bounty-questions-for-a-particular-tag#comment641421_375795) to get an example fulfilling the conditions.

Comment: Opposite direction: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242517/make-bounty-award-color-blue-in-summary-tab.

Comment: @Shadow How is that opposite? It seems the same to me. But thanks for finding that old question.

Comment: @PM2Ring opposite **direction** - same request, just in the form of a feature request. Not voting to close as duplicate because it's written in a very different style, so I don't feel comfortable using hammer for that.

Comment: @Shadow Ah, right. I guess that request is probably unlikely to be granted. But it'd be nice... Although what colour would you use if an answer gets accepted & receives a bounty simultaneously? Aqua? Blue & green checks? :)

Comment: @PM2Ring I'd just show two entries for the same question: green with the accept rep, and blue with bounty rep. :-)